# Remove duplicates column combinations from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ignore-duplicates

I want to remove duplicate combinations of sessionid, qf and qn from the following data

```
               sessionid             qf        qn         city
1  9cf571c8faa67cad2aa9ff41f3a26e38     cat   biddix          fresno
2  e30f853d4e54604fd62858badb68113a   caleb     amos                
3  2ad41134cc285bcc06892fd68a471cd7  daniel  folkers                
4  2ad41134cc285bcc06892fd68a471cd7  daniel  folkers                
5  63a5e839510a647c1ff3b8aed684c2a5 charles   pierce           flint
6  691df47f2df12f14f000f9a17d1cc40e       j    franz prescott+valley
7  691df47f2df12f14f000f9a17d1cc40e       j    franz prescott+valley
8  b3a1476aa37ae4b799495256324a8d3d  carrie mascorro            brea
9  bd9f1404b313415e7e7b8769376d2705    fred  morales       las+vegas
10 b50a610292803dc302f24ae507ea853a  aurora      lee                
11 fb74940e6feb0dc61a1b4d09fcbbcb37  andrew    price       yorkville
```

I read in the data as a data.frame and call it mydata. Heree is the code I have so far, but I need to know how to first sort the data.frame correctly. Secondly remove the duplicate combinations of sessionid, qf, and qn. And lastly graph in a histogram characters in the column qf

```
sortDATA<-function(name)
{
#sort the code by session Id, first name, then last name
sort1.name <- name[order("sessionid","qf","qn") , ]
#create a vector of length of first names
sname<-nchar(sort1.name$qf)
hist(sname)
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Working from the end of @Joran's answer, you can then plot a simple histogram with `plot(dat$qf, las=2)`. (The `las` argument is there to rotate the xlabels by 90 degrees).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`duplicated()` has a method for `data.frame`s, which is designed for just this sort of task:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4, 1:4), 
                 b = c(4:1, 4:1), 
                 d = LETTERS[1:8])

df[!duplicated(df[c("a", "b")]),]
#   a b d
# 1 1 4 A
# 2 2 3 B
# 3 3 2 C
# 4 4 1 D
```

Comment: how to remove these cross duplicate also?
Can It be done by duplicate function?

Answer (score 3):

In your example the repeated rows were entirely repeated.  `unique` works with data.frames.

```
udf <- unique( my.data.frame )
```

As for sorting... joran just posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To address your sorting problems, first reading in your example data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "               sessionid             qf        qn         city
1  9cf571c8faa67cad2aa9ff41f3a26e38     cat   biddix          fresno
2  e30f853d4e54604fd62858badb68113a   caleb     amos             NA   
3  2ad41134cc285bcc06892fd68a471cd7  daniel  folkers             NA   
4  2ad41134cc285bcc06892fd68a471cd7  daniel  folkers             NA   
5  63a5e839510a647c1ff3b8aed684c2a5 charles   pierce           flint
6  691df47f2df12f14f000f9a17d1cc40e       j    franz prescott+valley
7  691df47f2df12f14f000f9a17d1cc40e       j    franz prescott+valley
8  b3a1476aa37ae4b799495256324a8d3d  carrie mascorro            brea
9  bd9f1404b313415e7e7b8769376d2705    fred  morales       las+vegas
10 b50a610292803dc302f24ae507ea853a  aurora      lee              NA  
11 fb74940e6feb0dc61a1b4d09fcbbcb37  andrew    price       yorkville ",sep = "",header = TRUE)
```

and then you can use `arrange` from **plyr**,

```
arrange(dat,sessionid,qf,qn)
```

or using base functions,

```
with(dat,dat[order(sessionid,qf,qn),])
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use duplicated twice:

```
> df

  a  b c    d
1 1  2 A 1001
2 2  4 B 1002
3 3  6 B 1002
4 4  8 C 1003
5 5 10 D 1004
6 6 12 D 1004
7 7 13 E 1005
8 8 14 E 1006

> df[!(duplicated(df[c("c","d")]) | duplicated(df[c("c","d")], fromLast = TRUE)), ]

a  b c    d
1 1  2 A 1001
4 4  8 C 1003
7 7 13 E 1005
8 8 14 E 1006
```