# Remove duplicate combinations in R

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, combinations

I am using R and I would like to remove combinations in a data.frame. Unique function does not seem to do the job.

```
  a b c
1 1 4 A
2 2 3 B
3 1 5 C
4 4 1 A
5 5 1 C
6 3 2 B
7 3 2 E
```

And I would like to get something that looks like this, keeping just one combination of column a and b (column c is a frequency measure):

```
       a b c
     1 1 4 A
     2 2 3 B
     3 1 5 C
```

Thanks a lot!

PS: The origin of the problem is the dcast function returning this error: 
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length ([R reshape2 'Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463591/r-reshape2-aggregation-function-missing-defaulting-to-length))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates column combinations from a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422415/remove-duplicates-column-combinations-from-a-dataframe-in-r) and [removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order)

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[c("a", "b")], 1, sort))), ]
  a b c
1 1 4 A
2 2 3 B
3 1 5 C
```

Where:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L), 
  b = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
  c = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "E")
)
```